# Binary Search tree, node deletion crash

Tags: c, pointers, tree, binary-search-tree

I coded a Binary Search tree. Every function works just fine, but the "deletenode". This method is supposed to delete the node which *p is pointing at.

However if the node is a leaf it prints the tree without the node and crashes.
If the node is no leaf it doesnt even print the tree and crashes.

I dont see any possible way to recreate the problem in less code, because i dont know where the problem is supposed to be. **I'm Sorry**.

Maybe someone can load it up and see where the problem is, because im really desperate.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void *malloc(size_t size);
void free(void *ptr);

struct tnode {
    int content;
    struct tnode *left; /* left subtree */
    struct tnode *right; /* right subtree */
};


struct tnode *talloc(void) /* reserves memory*/
{
    return (struct tnode *) malloc(sizeof(struct tnode));
}

struct tnode *addelement(struct tnode *p, int i)   /* addelement: adds new node */
{
    int cond;
    if(p == NULL) {
        p = talloc(); /* make a new node */ p->content = i;
        p->left = p->right = NULL;
    } else if(p->content == i) {
        return p;
    } else if(i < p->content) /* goes to the left side */ p->left = addelement(p->left, i);
    else /* goes to the right side */ p->right = addelement(p->right, i);
    return p;
}

struct tnode *addtree(struct tnode *top, struct tnode *p) /* adds subtree to main tree*/
{
    if(p == NULL)
        return top;
    else
        return addtree(addtree(addelement(top, p->content), p->right), p->left);
}

int printtree_preorder(struct tnode *p) /* prints tree in preorder*/
{
    if(p != NULL) {
        printf("%d \n", p->content);
        printtree_preorder(p->left);
        printtree_preorder(p->right);
    }
    return 0;
}

int printtree_inorder(struct tnode *p)  /* prints tree in inorder*/
{
    if(p != NULL) {
        printtree_inorder(p->left);
        printf("%d \n", p->content);
        printtree_inorder(p->right);
    }
    return 0;
}

int printtree_postorder(struct tnode *p)    /* prints tree in postorder*/
{
    if(p != NULL) {
        printtree_postorder(p->left);
        printtree_postorder(p->right);
        printf("%d \n", p->content);
    }
    return 0;
}

struct tnode *searchnode(struct tnode *p, int nodtodelete) /* pointer is set on the node which is supposed to be deleted  */
{
    if(p == NULL) {
        printf("Baum ist leer oder Element nicht vorhanden \n");
        return 0;
    }
    if(p->content == nodtodelete) {
        return p;
    }
    if(p->content < nodtodelete) {
        return searchnode(p->right, nodtodelete);
    }
    if(p->content > nodtodelete) {
        return searchnode(p->left, nodtodelete);
    }
}

struct tnode  *deletenode(struct tnode *p, struct tnode *pBaum) /* Is supposed to delete the node which the *p is pointing at */
{
    if((p->left == NULL) && (p->right == NULL)) {
        free(p);
        printf("Ist Blatt \n");
        return pBaum;
    }
    if((p->left == NULL) && (p->right != NULL)) {
        struct tnode *rechterTeilbaum = p->right;
        free(p);
        pBaum = addtree(pBaum, rechterTeilbaum);
        return pBaum;

    }
    if((p->right == NULL) && (p->left != NULL)) {
        struct tnode *linkerTeilbaum = p->left;
        free(p);
        pBaum = addtree(pBaum, linkerTeilbaum);
        return pBaum;
    }
    if((p->left != NULL) && (p->right != NULL)) {
        struct tnode *rechterTeilbaum = p->right;
        struct tnode *linkerTeilbaum = p->left;
        free(p);
        pBaum = addtree(pBaum, rechterTeilbaum);
        pBaum = addtree(pBaum, linkerTeilbaum);
        return pBaum;
    }
}

int main() {
    struct tnode *Baum = NULL;
    struct tnode *tmpPos = NULL;

    Baum = addelement(Baum, 10);
    Baum = addelement(Baum, 30);
    Baum = addelement(Baum, 20);
    Baum = addelement(Baum, 35);

    tmpPos = searchnode(Baum, 35);

    if(tmpPos != 0) {
        printf("Zu loeschendes Element: %d \n", tmpPos->content);
        Baum = deletenode(tmpPos, Baum);
    }

    printf("Inorder Ausgabe\n");
    printtree_inorder(Baum);

    printf("Postorder Ausgabe\n");
    printtree_postorder(Baum);

    printf("Preorder Ausgabe\n");
    printtree_preorder(Baum);
}
```

Comment: Ask yourself: how does an inner node get notified if one of its children gets removed? I.e. how will it know, if its `right` or `left` pointers are still valid once you called `deletenode`? Your programme crashes, because during printing at some point you're trying to dereference a dangling pointer.

Comment: @BeyelerStudios if i call 'deletenode' the memory which 'p' is pointing at is cleared in every case. So if im correct this will also delete the 'left' and 'right' pointer which causes them to be invalid. If im wrong though, feel free to tell me how i can solve my problem

Comment: You're wrong. Please read a tutorial on pointers i.e. look up *dangling pointer*: raw pointers are not updated magically (they are simple memory addresses), you need to invalidate `left` and `right` of the parent of the deleted node yourself.

Comment: @BeyelerStudios because i just started working with pointers I'm not really sure how to do that. Do you mind giving me an example for my code specificly? I tried setting  'p = NULL;' after evey 'free(p)' but that didnt work.

Answer (score 1):

In the deletenode function, you aren't checking to see if p is NULL before you try to dereference it. Are you segfaulting?

Comment: yeah forgot to add the NULL check, but im not segfaulting.

Comment: Im compiling everything with CodeBlocks, i dont get any errors or warnings. It just tells me that the .exe stopped working and crashes. If you compile it yourself you most likely will see the same.